# Inverse of a block matrix with particular entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra

Good afternoon;
I have the following block matrix:
$X$ = $$\pmatrix{U&M\\M&V}$$

Where $U,V,M$ are square matrices of size $n\times n $, and it holds:

$U^2 = V^2 = M^2 = I$ ; with $I$: Identity matrix.

I am trying to find the explicit inverse of $X$ in function of  $U,V,M$ without using many inverse calculation. I have found the direct inverse with classic operations that involves the calculus of the inverse of the block sub-matrices; but I am pretty sure that the inverse can be calculated in funtion of $U,V,M$, please any suggestions are appreciated a lot.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe calculating $X^2$ could give a hint.

Answer (score 2):

The matrices $U$, $V$, and $M$ are involutory and hence are nonsingular. Let $S_U = V - MUM$ be the Schur complement of $X$ with respect to $U$. Then $X$ is invertible if and only if $S_U$ is invertible, and

$$
X^{-1} = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
U + UMS_U^{-1}MU & -UMS_U^{-1}\\
-S_U^{-1}MU & S_U^{-1}\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Note that if $X$ is invertible then you only have to calculate the explicit inverse of $S_U$ once in order to calculate $X^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

You may express the inverse by using [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Background). As square roots of $I$ in general do not commute, I don't expect any further simplification.